# Limite multivariate function

Tags: limits

for $x,y \in [0,\pi]$, find 
$$
\lim_{y,x\rightarrow 0,\, x\le y} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{\sin^2(y)-\sin^2(x)}
$$

I found that it is equivalent to 
$$
\lim_{y,x\rightarrow 0,\, x\le y} \frac{xy}{y^2-x^2}
$$

By plotting, I know that the limit is 0.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you approach 0 along the line y=x? and compare it to an approach along the line y = 2x.

Comment: @DougM The function doesn't exist for $\;x=y\;$ : it cannot approach anything on it.

Comment: So what does that say about the limit?

Comment: @DougM I don't get your point: I think it says nothing. The function $\;\frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y}\;$ isn't defined on the line $\;x=y\;$ , yet its limit at the origin is zero...

Comment: The limit is undefined at 0.

Comment: @DougM What? The existence or inexistence of a limit at some point doesn't not *necessarily* depend on the value of the function at that point, not even on whether the function is defined on that point. The question is that in the example I gave the limit exists, and it is zero by the way, though the function isn't defined on the line $\;x=y\;$ and thus one cannot approach the origin on this line.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=y/n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Note that
$$
{xy\over y^2-x^2}={nx^2\over(n^2-1)x^2}={n\over n^2-1}
$$
which shows $$\lim_{y,x\to0+,x\le y}{xy\over y^2-x^2}$$ doesn't exist. So the $2$nd limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

With $xy/(y^2-x^2),$ here's what I see: A numerator that is nonzero on the line $y=x$, and a denominator that vanishes on that line. That kind of situation always spells trouble. Even avoiding the line $y=x,$ such a function will be unbounded in any deleted neighborhood of $(0,0).$ Thus there is no hope for a limit. In this problem, you could look at the path $y = x+x^2$ for example.